# Hiding a router in a college dorm

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am looking to buy a router to plug in to an ethernet jack so that I can plug both my ps4 and xbox one into a single port (second port is used by my computer's cat5e cable).

I essentially want it to work like a switch, except my understanding is that a router will internalize IP's where as a switch will use MAC addresses thus making it obvious there are multiple devices connected.

My understanding is that a router would look like a single IP since everything post router (xbox and ps4) have there IP's internalized as viewed by the router. I would essentially turn off the broadcast feature and use it exclusively as a switch so that a wifi sniffer couldn't detect it.

I understand if the network admin went through the trouble of analyzing the packets he could figure it out but I am just looking to not make it obvious. So my question is will a router look like a single IP with the packets being the only real giveaway?

Comment: Do you know there is a policy against having a switch plugged in? I can't imagine you're the first student that has wanted to more devices than there are ports. My first thought would be a call to their tech guys and ask

Comment: Any router/switch that supports NAT and has a DHCP server.  A large number of common devices support this, too long to list.  If the device comes with Wifi support I would turn that off as it will probably be detected.

Answer (score 2):

You've got your terms all mixed up. A WiFi sniffer has nothing to do with what you're talking about. In fact, WiFi has nothing at all to do with plugging a router into a network socket. Also your understanding about MAC addresses is probably a bit off, but I think I get where you're coming from.

Long story short - if you get a consumer router that has an ethernet port on the "WAN" side (not an ADSL or coaxial port), and you plug the "WAN" interface into your dorm's network socket, and you plug your Xbox and your PS4 into the "LAN" ports, then to the upstream network, they will only see a single MAC address.

HOWEVER, network administrators are not stupid. Depending on how their network is configured (e.g. 802.1x) this may not work, as devices on the network may require authentication.

So if you are having to "hide" a router, then you are probably breaking their ToS, which may mean that you put your entire internet access at risk.

However, if it's OK to have multiple devices plugged into the network, then you've got nothing to worry about, and you can probably just use a normal network switch.

Comment: Enforcing port security on a college dorm network would seem like an administrative nightmare, there are far too many situations where students would swap devices around.

Comment: @MichaelB you can do port security without having to register devices. 802.1x on supported devices (e.g. not an xbox or ps4), the operating system simply prompts you to log on with your credentials, that's all.

Comment: If the school requires 802.1X, all he needs is a NAT gateway that can run an 802.1X supplicant on its WAN port.

Comment: I use to register my LAN based devices when I was living in the dorms.  I also had to register my wireless devices.

Answer (score 0):

A switch and a router are two different devices.
A Switch is a Layer 2 device, which means every port is on the same broadcast domain (all the hosts connected to the port have to be in the same network in order to communicate with each other).
In a router, every port is on a different broadcast domain (every port is on a different network), and it can forward packets by checking a routing table.
Regarding MAC, both router and switches use MAC addresses, but that's another discussion and I would be here all day in order to explain it.

Basically you want a router with at least two L3 interfaces, and you want perform NAT overload (PAT) from one internal network, let's say that your PS4 and XBOX One Network, that are on the 192.168.2.0/24 network, to the 10.0.64.0/18 network (your network subnet), you can do it.
One rather cheap router that can do it --> http://routerboard.com/RB750Gr2

Keep in mind that you have to be allowed to manually set IP addresses.
You can check if it works by directly connecting a laptop and manually setting an IP address. If it works, it will work, if it doesn't...

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has an "Internet Connection Sharing" feature that I used. Then I got a Windows 2003 server and set up RRAS. Two nics enabled me to provide the campus network to my own LAN without presenting any router-manufacturer MAC.